# requirejs plugin loads module in fresh context

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to have a module load multiple times on a page, with a unique context for each instance.  There are two normal ways to do this.

1. the module can return a constructor
2. i can explicitly run the require method, providing a context id.

Either of these would work in my situation, but I want a third option.  :)

I want a requirejs plugin that will return a module to me in a fresh context.  ie,

```
require(["new!some/module"], function(SomeModule) {
    // SomeModule, here, is in its own context.  If i were to run this
    // method call again, SomeModule would be in a new context.
});
```

I've started looking into building a plugin to do this...

```
load: function (name, req, load, config) {
    var index = get_unique_index();
    req({context:index}, [name], function(value) {
        if(!config.isBuild){
            load(value);
        }
    });
}
```

but the {context:index} dict doesn't work here... thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. requireJs only prevents script from execute while required scripts are not loaded before. You cannot load the same script several times. The better way for you is to load, only once, a script that create a constructor and instanciate it as often as needed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the local req passed to load, use the global require function, just called require(). The local one passed to load is already bound to a context.